# Python list as JavaScript array is adding extra text

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, python-3.x

I created a Python array like this:

```
urlnamesend=[]
    baseurlImage='https://s3.amazonaws.com/'
    for i in urlname:
        urlnamesend.append(baseurlImage + i['image'])
```

Now I want to use this is Django template in JavaScript, but it's giving something like this, like adding `&#39` in every link. How I can get rid of it?

```
[&#39;https://s3.amazonaws.com/Events/Test1/1.jpg&#39;, 
&#39;https://s3.amazonaws.com/Events/Test1/2.jpg&#39;, 
&#39;https://s3.amazonaws.com/Test1/3.jpg&#39;,]
```

---

EDIT: `urlname` value is like `'Events/Test1/DSC_0397.jpg'`

Comment: can you show `urlname`? from the ASCII table, 39 is the code for apostrophe

Comment: urlname just containing  images name I am getting dynamically  @Lemayzeur . AND THEN i APPEND IN THIS WITH BASEURL

Comment: Note from the ASCII table, `&#39` is the code for apostrophe.

Comment: so can I remove from start and end from every image ? @Lemayzeur  in python

Comment: Just add an example of `urlname`, so I will show you how to do it

Comment: @Lemayzeur  done

Comment: @Lemayzeur  possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one url from `urlname` contains more than one apostrophe.
try removing all the apostrophes with `replace()`

```
# urlname = [] # UNKNOWN
urlnamesend=[]
baseurlImage='https://s3.amazonaws.com/'
for i in urlname:
   url = i['image'].replace("'","")
   urlnamesend.append(baseurlImage + url)
```

Comment: its still same :|

Comment: inside your for loop, add `print(i['image'])` to see each url string and add the output to your question